# Das Futur und Präsens um die Vergangenheit zu beschreiben

Tags: tense

In der letzten Gradingperiode dieses Schuljahres musste meine Deutschklasse einen Aufsatz über ein Thema unserer Wahl schreiben. Meiner ging um Anzeichen des Kalten Krieges in Nachkriegsdeutschland. Ein Satz im Aufsatz lautet

> «Die Alliierten wollten, dass Deutschland so gehindert wäre, dass das Land nie wieder eine Bedrohung für die Welt darstellen könnte.»

Meine Lehrerin hat diesen Satz korrigiert, und jetzt lautet er

> «Die Alliierten (...) so gehindert sein wird, (...) die Welt darstellen werden kann».

Meine Frage ist: Wieso würde man das Futur oder Präsens benutzen, anstatt den Konjunktiv II, um die Vergangenheit auf so eine Weise zu beschreiben?

Comment: Without having read the answer will be here I want to mention one thing: "...die Welt darstellen werden kann" is incredibly bad and unidiomatic and I am almost certain that it is also wrong. Your sentence may not be quite what they would write in a newspaper but it is better than the concoction of your teacher.

Comment: Die Korrekturen der Lehrerin klingen zumindest seltsam und sind vermutlich falsch. "Hindern, daß" ist zudem eine unglückliche Wortwahl. Ich würde den ursprünglichen Satz umformulieren: "Die Alliierten wollten sicherstellen, daß Deutschland nie wieder eine Bedrohung für die Welt darstellen kann."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Also, im Satz deiner Lehrerin ist auf jeden Fall schon mal ein *werden* zu viel. Der Satz lautet wenn schon:

> Die Alliierten wollten, dass Deutschland so gehindert sein wird, dass das Land nie wieder eine Bedrohung für die Welt darstellen kann.

Wie kommt man dahin?
"Die Alliierten wollten …" ist ja klar ein Punkt in der Vergangenheit. Alles, worauf du dich dann beziehst, spielt zeitlich danach. Überleg dir mal, du würdest zu der Zeit leben und würdest sagen, was du willst (erstmal unter der Voraussetzung, dass der Satz deiner Lehrerin optimal wäre).

> Ich will, dass Deutschland so gehindert sein wird, dass das Land nie wieder eine Bedrohung für die Welt darstellen kann.

Was ich damit sagen will, dass es erstmal egal ist, dass das, auf was sich der Abschnitt bezieht, für dich gerade in der Vergangenheit liegt, sondern die Relevanz ist, wo es sich zeitlich zum Hauptsatz befindet.

So ganz toll klingt der Satz aber so oder so nicht. In diesem Satz wurde das Futur 2 verwendet. Futur 2 wird für eine Vermutung verwendet. Aber du vermutest nicht, dass

> Deutschland wird gehindert sein.

Eine im Futur 2 korrekte Vermutung wäre beispielsweise:

> Mein Auto wird bis nächste Woche wieder repariert sein.

Also bleibt nur noch Futur 1 oder das Präsens übrig, welches im Deutschen eben auch für die Zukunft verwendet wird.

Ich würde in diesem Fall es etwa so ausdrücken:

> Ich will [oder Die Alliierten wollten], dass Deutschland so gehindert wird, dass das Land nie wieder eine Bedrohung für die Welt darstellen kann.

Also Präsens.

Dein Satz ist in sofern nicht ganz richtig, weil du eben den Konjunktiv verwendest. Das passt hier so nicht. Überleg dir wieder, du würdest eine Aussage über die Zukunft machen:

> Ich möchte, dass du so lange essen würdest, bis du satt wärest.

Da erkennst du wahrscheinlich leichter, dass das sehr merkwürdig klingt. Hier sagst du ja auch eher:

> Ich möchte, dass du so lange isst, bis du satt bist.

Randnotiz: Das Wort *hindern* klingt hier auch etwas fehl am Platz. Ich kenne jetzt nicht den ganzen Kontext, und worauf es sich genau bezieht, aber etwas in der Form wie "… dass Deutschland in ihren Mitteln so eingeschränkt wird, …" könnte besser klingen.

Comment: _Hindern, daß_ ist in jedem Fall falsch. Eine Infinitivkonstruktion würde gehen, wahrscheinlich braucht man zusätzlich noch ein _daran_.

Comment: Am Rande: Der Konjunktiv wäre in Ordnung, wenn Du betonen wolltest, dass der Wille der Alliierten nicht umgesetzt geworden oder utopisch sei.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Richtig, aber dann wäre es etwas in der Art "Die Alliierten wollten, dass Deutschland so gehindert gewesen wäre, dass das Land nie wieder eine Bedrohung für die Welt hätte darstellen können."

Comment: @Em1: Wieso jetzt die Vergangenheit? Ich würde aus den gleichen Gründen wie für den Indikativsatz hier das Präsens verwenden. Denn der Wunsch, ob realistisch oder nicht, bezieht sich ja auch auf die Gegenwart und Zukunft.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Um, wenn ich dich richtig verstanden habe, willst du die Betonung darauf setzen, dass das Vorhaben gescheitert sei. Aber das Beispiel ist eh nicht das beste. Nehmen wir mal ein einfaches: "Ich will, dass du gehst. Ich wünschte, du würdest gehen. - Ich wollte, dass du gehst. Ich wünschte, du wärest gegangen." So wie ich es verstehe, sind wir beim vierten: Zurückblickend erkennen wir erst, dass es irreal war oder zumindest nicht so eingetroffen ist. - Durch das Hinzufügen dieser Zusatzinformation, können wir das anders handhaben, als im Indikativfall, wo wir ja neutral sind.

Comment: @EM1: Dein Beispiel hakt daran, dass *gehen* hier nicht zeitlich ausgedehnt ist und dass im ursprünglichen Beispiel die Irrealität nicht notwendigerweise rückblickend festgestellt werden muss (mal abgesehen davon, dass dieser Wunsch auch für alle Zeit irreal bleibt, wenn er schon rückblickend irreal war). Deshalb ein anderes Beispiel: »Damals wünschte ich, dass ich nie [gestorben wäre / stürbe / sterben würde].« Option 1 ist klar unsinnig, da es aussagt, dass ich bereits tot bin. 2 und 3 (Irrealis Gegenwart/Futur) beziehen hingegen auch auch die Zukunft vom Zeitpunkt des Wünschens mit ein.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Fair enough. Irgendwie klingt es trotzdem nicht richtig in OPs Satz.

Answer (score 2):

> «Die Alliierten wollten, dass Deutschland so gehindert wäre, dass
>   das Land nie wieder eine Bedrohung für die Welt darstellen könnte.»

Was ist das für ein Kuddelmuddel? Wäre Deutschland gehindert nie wieder eine Bedrohung zu sein, dann würde dies bedeuten, dass die Alliierten Deutschland rasch zu einer Bedrohung machen wollten.

> «Die Alliierten wollten Deutschland hindern wieder eine Bedrohung 
>   für die Welt zu sein.»

Man kann es auch abschwächen zu *eine Bedrohung für die Welt sein zu können.*

oder auch, wenn man das darstellen so liebt:

> «Die Alliierten wollten Deutschland daran hindern wieder eine Bedrohung
>   für die Welt darzustellen.»

oder

> «Die Alliierten wollten Deutschland daran hindern wieder eine Bedrohung 
>   für die Welt darstellen zu können.»