# ein Gerundium oder Adjektiv + werden?

Tags: sentence-structure

Ich habe noch eine Frage bezüglich [meines Aufsatzes](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/8022/das-futur-und-prasens-um-die-vergangenheit-zu-beschreiben). Ich schrieb

> «Das Schwächen Deutschlands war nicht der einzige Grund, weshalb
>   Deutschland gespalten wurde.»

und meine Lehrerin korrigierte den Satz und jetzt lautet er so

> «Das schwächer werden Deutschlands...»

Warum würde man so eine Fügung hier benutzen, Adjektiv + werden, statt eines Gerundium?

Comment: Weitere Vorschläge (meiner Meinung nach besser): _die Schwächung Deutschlands_; _Deutschland zu schwächen_.

Comment: your answer was fine, the one for your teacher is missing what your trying to express in my opinion... since also the last correction of your teacher was questionable... she isn't a native speaker, is she?

Comment: Sie kommt aus der Schweiz

Comment: ops... ich hab' die Antwort auf Englisch geschrieben obwohl die Frage auf Deutsch war. Ist mir grad erst aufgefallen. Tut mir leid :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Wenn* man diese Konstruktion verwendet, müßte sie geschrieben werden als "Das Schwächerwerden". Aber beide Beispiele sind derart unüblich, daß viele Leser Schwierigkeiten hätten, sie zu verstehen. Die übliche Konstruktion ist "Die Schwächung Deutschlands...".

Answer (score 6):

The solution your teacher suggested is not what you were trying to express... or at least I think so.
As I understand your original sentence you wanted to ask this question:

> Why did the allies divide Germany?

Now, they can either do that because Germany is already weak or they can do it because they want to weaken it. Those are 2 different things (cause and effect reversed) and the answer should reflect that.

> Das Schwächerwerden Deutschlands war ein Grund für die Teilung.

This doesn't. It sounds as if Germany eventually (was) split partly because it was weakening. It does not express that Germany was split IN ORDER TO weaken it.
Hence, your teachers suggestion is wrong. Same goes for "die Schwächung Deutschlands". This is still ambiguous as to what happened first.

Your original sentence nicely captured that the weakening was inflicted upon Germany because of the nominalization of the transitive verb **schwächen**. The only problem is that nominalizations often sound a little stiff so you could either go for the following

> Deutschland zu schwächen war einer der Gründe aus dem Deutschland gespalten wurde.

But an even better choice would be to replace **Grund** by **Ziel** for that clearly communicates what is cause and what is effect.

> Die Schwächung Deutschlands war eines der Ziele der Spaltung des Landes.
>
> Deutschland zu schwächen war eines der Ziele seiner Spaltung.